# Only 25 libraries listed in local NuGet repository

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2022, nuget-package, nugetgallery

I am on VS2022 (17.+).

We have a local NuGet repository for host the in-house NuGets.  However, we just realized that in the NuGet Manager, it only lists 25 of 30 libraries.  To test the theory, we removed one of the libraries in the top of the list and sure enough the 26th library showed up in the NuGet Manager.

Anyone know how we can address this?  Thanks!

Comment: There is no problem on my side, could you please share related screenshots of this, and if possible, could you please upgrate to the latest vs?

Comment: And what is the specific version of vs on your side?

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT...17.8.4

Comment: By any chance, is your in-house feed using Sleet?  It generates static files, which means that it can't do dynamic responses to search requests. NuGet in VS asks for 25 search results, and will request another 25 when you scroll to the end of the results, asking the server to skip the first 25. But if the search service is a static file, it's going to return the same packages as the first 25 every time.

Comment: @zivkan...all the NuGets were generated by VS's build.  We just dump them in a folder and put them in a share

Comment: I encountered a similar issue on the new version of VS. But an older version is no problem, I think you could report this issue and you could use older version to avoid this problem.